# secured environment for web App Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

i want to deploy a 3 tier Application on azure web App.

1. deployed the Application in a Azure Web App and linked this webApp to a virtual network.
2. this application was using an API, which i deployed in another Azure WebApp
3. the Api uses a DataBAse, which is azure Sql DB.

I want the API to be in a private Subnet.IN other words i Want only the WebApp deployed in step 1. to access this Api, which is again deployed in Azure WebApp. 
How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you referenced [Network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg)?

Comment: yes! we cant associate NSG with a gateway subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your topology correctly this is the scenario you want to achieve:

[Front End] --> [API] --> [Database]

Front End should be publicly accessible.
API should be only accessible through the vnet
Database should only be accessible to the API app.

There are 2 ways to achieve this depending on your security tolerance.

**1) More secure**

Deploy your API to an **[Internal Load Balanced App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer)**. By doing this your API app would only be reachable from the vnet. Then you would need to deploy the Web app an enable the [vNET Integration feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)  so that the 2 apps can talk to each other.

**2) Less secure**
Deploy both your api app and web app to regular app service plans, enable vnet integration feature and then [configure ip restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-ip-restrictions) on the API app to allow traffic on the ip addresses that your web app will use. You can find this under the properties of the app you create:

[image]

Under this scenario, your api would still technically have a public endpoint, but traffic on this would be limited/blocked by your ip restriction rules.

Comment: Hi Byron,Thanks for your answer.This is what i want to achieve but dont want to use ASE,instead want to block all the traffic to the API.For this purpose i created a user defined Route and added a rule but still the API is available Publicly. Moreover,due to some reasons we cant attach NSG to webApp. Is there any way to block the traffic to the API ? And again both the web App and API are in same Vnet and are attached to the same gateway subnet.

Comment: Without App Service environments the second option "Less Secure" is the best you can do.